# Obtener enlace de descarga directo de Mega.nz con nodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, requests

Quiero obtener en enlace directo de descarga de una imagen alojada en Mega.nz. Utilizo nodejs para hacer el request

```
const request = require('request')

let url = 'https://mega.nz/#!SttF0BiC!BXQIrgxB9Q5qWmccdjMnsISUCyRV4Hr6f-v5RjQxB_w'
let api = 'https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs?id=0&domain=meganz&lang=es'

let id_link = url.match(/!(.+?)!/)

request({
  method: 'POST', uri: api, body: '[{"a":"g","p":"SttF0BiC","ad":1,"esid":""}]'
}, (e, r, b) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(b));
})
```

obtengo este JSON como respuesta:

```
[
  {
    s: 30751,
    at: 'KxaM1xBhlW8oAc1zECKfnk7uSulGtHy0FKagNNF2iFo',
    msd: 1,
    fa: '882:1*0jPaMigP8EU/882:0*QpB5s69lt7s',
    ad: false,
    popad: false
  }
]
```

Sin embargo a partir de este punto no se como proceder

Comment: Has intentado usar alguna biblioteca?. Mega tiene un [SDK en C++](https://docs.mega.nz/sdk/doc/index.html) y también hay bibliotecas para hacer todo el proceso como [megajs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/megajs). Yo creo que por temas de seguridad, intentar llamar directamente a los endpoints del sitio va a ser problemático